# How to parallelize for loops in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert some Pandas code to Pyspark, which will run on an EMR cluster. This is my first time working with Pyspark, and I am not sure what is the optimal way to code the objective. The job is trying to achieve the following:

- There is a base dataframe with schema like so:

  - institution_id, user_id, st_date
- For every unique institution_id, get all users
- For every user for the institution_id, take all unique st_dates in sorted order, get the difference between pairs of consecutive st_dates and output a dictionary

Here is what the code looks like as of now:

```py
def process_user(current_user, inst_cycles): 
    current_user_dates = np.sort(current_user.st_date.unique()) 
    if current_user_dates.size > 1: 
        prev_date = pd.to_datetime(current_user_dates[0]).date() 
        for current_datetime in current_user_dates[1:]:
            current_date = pd.to_datetime(current_datetime).date()
            month = current_date.month
            delta = current_date - prev_date
            cycle_days = delta.days
            inst_cycles[month][cycle_days] += 1
            prev_date = current_date 
    return inst_cycles

def get_inst_monthly_distribution(current_inst):
    inst_cycles = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)) 
    inst_user_ids = current_inst.select('user_id').distinct().collect() 
    for _, user_id in enumerate(inst_user_ids): 
        user_id_str = user_id[0] 
        current_user = current_inst.filter(current_inst.user_id == user_id_str) 
        inst_cycles = process_user(current_user, inst_cycles) 
    return inst_cycles

def get_monthly_distributions(inst_ids, df): 
    cycles = {} 
    for _, inst_id_str in enumerate(inst_ids.keys()): 
        current_inst = df.filter(df.inst_id == inst_id_str)
        cycles[inst_id_str] = get_inst_monthly_distribution(current_inst)
    return cycles

def execute(): 
    df = load_data() # df is a Spark dataframe
    inst_names = get_inst_names(df) 
    monthly_distributions = get_monthly_distributions(inst_names, df)
```

I think this code is not taking advantage of the parallelism of Spark, and can be coded in a much better way without the for loops. Is that correct?

Comment: It would be much better if you:
1. Provide some sample input and output
2. Simplify your code and focus only on the piece(s) that you need help with

Comment: You can look into UDFs and Pandas UDFs

Comment: you can simple do a join on different tables and that should be it. Otherwise you could read each table in a different dataframe and join those dataframes instead of looping through it. Looping would kill the parallelism.